# Type definitions and type inference in F#

Tags: f#

I have two example types, defined in this order:

```
type Quote = {QuoteNum: decimal option; ShipToID: decimal option}
type Sales = {SalesNum: decimal option; ShipToID: decimal option}
```

and I'm trying to write a function that can accept a both types:

```
let fx (y: Map<decimal option, _ list>) = 
    y
    |> Map.map (fun key list -> list
                                   |> List.map (fun x -> x.ShipToID))
```

When I try to pass a `Map<decimal option, Quote list>` to the function, I get an error:

```
Type mismatch. Expecting a
Map<decimal option,Sales list>    
but given a
    Map<decimal option,Quote list>
```

I would have thought that I'd be able to pass a map of both types to the function, but the compiler seems to be inferring that only a `Map<decimal option, Sales list>` is acceptable to the function.  I suspect that the compiler "sees" the `Sales` type most recently and assumes that that's what the function needs.  I thought I had made the function relatively generic by including the `_` in the type annotation.

How can I make the function accept both types?  Can I do this without redefining the types themselves?

Comment: The types you've defined aren't maps, but record types, and they're different.

Answer (score 4):

Your suspicions are correct. F# needs to infer a single concrete type there, so will use the most recent matching type it finds.

You can make it work by defining an interface with `ShipToID` field and have both types implement it (not sure if that counts as redefining the types for you), or by providing a getter function for extracting the field value (which would let you keep the function generic):

```
let fx (shipToIdGetter: 'a -> decimal option) (y: Map<decimal option, 'a list>) = 
    y
    |> Map.map (fun key list -> 
                   list
                   |> List.map (fun x -> shipToIdGetter x))
```

Your code would work as written if F# supported row polymorphism (which happens to be the case for OCaml).

Answer (score 4):

While I believe that `scrwtp's` answer is the way to go, you also have the choice to use inline and [member constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/generics/constraints) (or static duck typing...if thats a valid term). For the sake of completeness:

```
type Quote = {QuoteNum: decimal option; ShipToID: decimal option}
type Sales = {SalesNum: decimal option; ShipToID: decimal option}

let inline fx (y: Map<decimal option, 'a list>) = 
    let inline getId x = ( ^a : (member ShipToID : decimal option) x)

    y |> Map.map (fun key list -> list |> List.map getId)


let q : Quote = { QuoteNum = None; ShipToID = None}
let s : Sales = { SalesNum = None; ShipToID = None}

fx <| Map.ofList [ None, [q]]
fx <| Map.ofList [ None, [s]]
```

The `getId` function uses the rather obscure syntax to call the `ShipToID` member based on `^a`'s expected structure.

Comment: FYI - The terminology for this is "statically resolved type parameters" - See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters